# Why doesn't the faac package support mp4?

Tags: sound, encoding, mp4, aac

In Ubuntu 13.10, `faac` doesn't support MP4.
If you run `faac --help` you get:

> Freeware Advanced Audio Coder
>
> FAAC 1.28
>
> Usage: faac [options] infiles ...
>
> Options:
>
> -q     Set quantizer quality.
>
> -b     Set average bitrate to x kbps. (ABR, lower quality
>   mode)
>
> -c    Set the bandwidth in Hz. (default=automatic)
>
> -o X        Set output file to X (only for one input file)
>
> -r      Use RAW AAC output file.
>
> -P      Raw PCM input mode (default 44100Hz 16bit stereo).
>
> -R      Raw PCM input rate.
>
> -B      Raw PCM input sample size (8, 16 (default), 24 or 32bits).
>
> -C      Raw PCM input channels.
>
> -X      Raw PCM swap input bytes
>
> -I    Input channel config, default is 3,4 (Center third, LF
>   fourth)
>
> **MP4 specific options:**
>
> **MP4 support unavailable.**
>
> Documentation:
>
> --license   Show the FAAC license.
>
> --help  Show this abbreviated help.
>
> --long-help Show complete help.
>
> More tips can be found in the audiocoding.com Knowledge Base at
>
> http://www.audiocoding.com/wiki/

In previous versions, I could run `faac` with `-w` and `--artist`, `--album`, etc. options, and now I can't.

Comment: A package rebuild solution now here: http://askubuntu.com/a/739687/57576

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was removed due to licensing issues -

```
faac (1.28-5) unstable; urgency=low

[ Andres Mejia ]
Disable mp4v2 support.
This only disables mp4v2 for the faac utility program. The faac
utility is GPL-2 but the mp4v2 library is MPL-1.1. The two licenses
are incompatible with each other.
```

So if you wish back then you'll need to either downgrade faac & libfaac0 to the faac (1.28-4) packages or simply get the current source & rebuild with `libmp4v2-dev` installed.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else finding this question, yes mp4v2 was removed. Rebuilding with the library went smoothly with the following hints:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep faac
apt-get source faac
cd faac-*
```

That should get you into the source directory. Edit debian/rules to remove the "--without-mp4v2" part. For me it meant removing the entire override_dh_auto_configure section.

```
sudo apt-get install libmp4v2-dev
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

My computer already had all the software for building packages installed, so consider this just some hints to finish up the build.